# Windows Batch - Service cycling with validation failing in for loop

Tags: windows, batch, services

I'm trying to set up some validation/timers to wait should the service take longer to cycle. If it fails, I will use something else to parse the log file and email me an alert should it fail.

For some reason I am getting a syntax error at the for loop. If I remove the else statement it works fine. But I can't find anything wrong with the syntax in the else statement.

```
@echo off
set ServiceName="My Service Name"
set logPath="C:\Program Files\Application"

::Start Service Maintenance
set now=[%DATE:~10,14%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%T%TIME:~0,8%]

for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query %ServiceName% ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
@echo %now% - For Loop >> %logPath%\ServiceManagmentLog.txt
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "STOPPED" (
  @echo %now% - Service Stopped - %ServiceName% >> %logPath%\ServiceManagmentLog.txt ) else (
    @echo %now% - The service doens't seem to be stopping, waiting another 5 seconds and trying again >> %logPath%\ServiceManagmentLog.txt
    ping -n 6 127.0.0.1 > nul
    sc start %ServiceName%
    ping -n 6 127.0.0.1 > nul
    for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%I in ('sc query %ServiceName% ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
      if /I "%%I" NEQ "STOPPED"( 
      @echo %now% - Service Stopped - %ServiceName% >> %logPath%\ServiceManagmentLog.txt    ) else (
      set stopError="%ServiceName% Failed to Stop"
      @echo %now% - ALERT - There seems to be an issue stopping %ServiceName% ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  )
```

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Comment: You have two `for` loops and two `else` statements. Which one is not working?

Comment: It was just formatting, once I fiddled with it for a bit it worked fine.

Comment: Leave the original formatting in place. Post an answer with the correct one, preferably mentioning *where* the fix was.

Comment: I never changed the formatting of the original code. But I will post as an answer in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer was a formatting error. I'd missed out the trailing `)`

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query %serviceName% ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
@echo %now% - For Loop >> %logPath%\ServiceManagmentLog_IC_%arg1%.txt
    if /I "%%H" EQU "STOPPED" (
        @echo %now% - Service Stopped - %serviceName% >> %logPath%\ServiceManagmentLog_IC_%arg1%.txt 
    ) else (
        @echo %now% - The service doens't seem to be stopping, waiting another %arg2% seconds and trying again >> %logPath%\ServiceManagmentLog_IC_%arg1%.txt
        ping -n %arg2% 127.0.0.1 > nul
        sc stop %serviceName%
        ping -n %arg2% 127.0.0.1 > nul
        for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query %serviceName% ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
            if /I "%%H" EQU "STOPPED" ( 
                    @echo %now% - Service Stopped - %serviceName% >> %logPath%\ServiceManagmentLog_IC_%arg1%.txt
                ) else (
                    @echo %now% - ALERT - There seems to be an issue stopping %serviceName% >> %logPath%\ServiceManagmentLog_IC_%arg1%.txt
                ) 
        ) 
    )
)
```

Comment: I checked it twice, there was no missing ). You probably missed it since it was at the end of the last echo line.  

It just doesn't like " ) else ( " being broken over multiple lines.

Could you please alter the title to what it was previously, just so there is no confusion should others find this post.